# Populating a ListView using FrameLayouts

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I'm currently following Udacity android development free courses, but I got an idea about an app and wanted to try out some of the stuff I just learned.

My problem is the following; I was trying to make a ListView out of some FrameLayouts. I'm using this FrameLayouts as i dont want to create a list of strings, but a list of "Boxes" I just made up. I tried to use an ArrayAdapter template using frameLayouts but compiler says i need to use TextView. What can i do here?

The final idea is to get some engine like the one that shows up in this page. promedioponderado.herokuapp.com

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got a type you want to display, say something like this:

```
class Foo{
    final int bar;
    Foo(int bar){this.bar = bar;}
}
```

You can override the `View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method of your adapter and do something like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_frame_layout_thingy, parent, false);

EditText box= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.my_box);
box.setText("Value is" + getItem(position).bar);
```

and remember to return `view`

For more details, I recommend you take a look at how `Adapter`s work, something like [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) seems to be a good starting point.

If you don't understanding what's the whole `class Foo` thing, I would recommend you look into Java fundamentals as starting Android programming without some basic understanding of Java is rather hard.